# Extjs4 xtype 'combo' not replacing html encoded text with symbol

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have select-box generated using xtype combo. And all options of this combo are generated using some user entered value. Server send these options of select box as html encoded value.
I have one option as `"& lt;anil& gt;"` which will be parsed by browser as `<anil>`.

Now when i click on drop down arrow of select box in select list being shown i can see correct parsing as "" but when i click this value  then selected value being shown is `"& lt;anil& gt;"`.

I am using extjs4. Any hint?

Comment: Can you post the complete code? You could also look at Ext.Component.query("#something")[0] and find the Raw value to help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to combo box and it worked.

```
getDisplayValue: function(){
                                if(this.displayTplData[0]) return Ext.htmlDecode(this.displayTplData[0].mapper_name);// Decode HTML
                                return this.displayTpl.apply(this.displayTplData);
                            },
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change every value of your xtype combo like this:

find the id first (by console.log)...

Ext.get('mycomboboxfieID').setValue(Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode(val))

or use

console.log(Ext.getCmp('yourcomboname').getRawValue());
and find the right point to setRawValue(Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode(val))